# asm ("fldl %0"...) in DOS, Intel syntax?

Tags: assembly, dos, inline-assembly, turbo-c++, x87

I'm working on a retro project trying to compile some test code in Borland Turbo C++/DosBox.

I have this function:

```
double sin(double x){
   asm ("fldl %0;"
        "fsin;"
        "fstpl %0" : "+m"(x));
   return x;
}
```

I figure it returns the sin value of x, but I'm otherwise lost.

The error is: Undefined symbol 'fldl'

Can anyone explain this function in Intel asm syntax?

I can't figure it out, I've only ever coded 16bit DOS asm code and no floating point.

Kind Regards
/Jacob

Comment: `fld` is the intel syntax, with a size specifier, e.g. `fld qword ptr` or similar. How to access arguments depends on your compiler and calling convention but maybe `fld qword ptr [x]; fsin; fstp qword ptr [x]` will work.

Comment: Turbo C++ doesn't error on the `:` separating the input/output constraint?  From [Creating Inline Assembly code(TASM) in Turbo C++ 3.0 from a documentation file](//stackoverflow.com/q/39484266), it looks like it uses incompatible syntax.  This is GNU C extended asm syntax https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  And BTW, this is very inefficient inline asm.  It should just use a `"+t"` constraint (top of the x87 stack) and leave the `fld` + `fst` to the compiler. `asm("fsin" : "+t"(x));`  This stupid version forces a store/reload of the result, and the input if it inlines.

Comment: Same as [Operand type mismatch in x87 inline assembly in a Linux kernel module](//stackoverflow.com/q/35280254).  (You can't safely use x87 inside a kernel module, but the syntax is correct.)

Comment: I tried changing to this: asm(fld qword ptr [x]; fsin; fstp qword ptr [x];); Now I get Expression syntax error, and undefined fsin and fstp.

Comment: Put them on separate lines, without the semicolons.

Comment: I changed from asm(...) to asm{...} and removed simicolons and now I only get one error: Expression syntax at the fsin line.

Comment: I've put them on separate lines without semicolons and if I uncomment fsin the function compiles. Otherwise I get Expression syntax

Comment: Should work ... try `fsin st0` or `fsin st(0)`. As a last resort, go for `db 0xd9, 0xfe` to emit the machine code by hand.

Comment: The st0/st(0) didn't work, but I tried compiling an example with fsin in TASM, and here I got a CPU related error. Do you know how to specify the target CPU in Borland? The db 0xd9, 0xfe did compile.

Comment: I don't get it. I just upgraded to Borland C++ 3.1 and set instruction set to 386/floating point to 287/387, but get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the target CPU must be at least 386.

so the function should be:

```
double sin(double x){
    asm{
        fld qword ptr [x]
        fsin
        fstp qword ptr [x]
    }
    return x;
}
```

I've gotten similar code to compile in TASM with .386 after .MODEL "size"